# Error: reading Backup Vault (AWSTargetBackupVault): couldn't find resource….. getting this erro while creating backup vaullts and plan via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, backup, database-backups

Im trying to create a awa backup plan via terraform
For that i have code creating aws backup vaults.
While terraform apply im getting this error even though the vaults are getting created on the console

> Error: reading Backup Vault (AWSTargetBackupVault): couldn't find resource

```
Error: reading Backup Vault (AWSTargetBackupVault): couldn't find resource module.build.aws_backup_vault.target_vault[0],
on • ./ . ./. ./modules/aws_build/image_table.tf line
 in resource "aws_backup_vault" "target_v resource "aws_backup_vault" "target_vault" (“
```

I tried adding depends_on in the aws backup plan
But that didnt do anything

I trying to create backup cross region
So going to use two backup vaults
These errors come while creating the vaults and backup plan for the first time.

Comment: At the least share your terraform script

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and I added "TF_LOG=Debug" before my "terrafom apply"

> TF_LOG=Debug Terraform apply"

And seeing the logs I was missing IAM permissions:

"backup:CreateBackupVault",
"backup:PutBackupVaultAccessPolicy",
"backup:PutBackupVaultNotifications",
"backup:TagResource",
"backup:DeleteBackupPlan",
"backup:DeleteBackupSelection",
"backup:DescribeBackupVault"
"backup:DeleteBackupVault"
"backup:CreateBackupPlan"
"backup:CreateBackupSelection"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).